# consuming web service (for the first time) in php

Tags: php, web-services, soap

It took me a while to get soap configured in php. Now I'm just trying to learn about it. I'm using the web service here to learn:

http://www.webservicex.net/WCF/ServiceDetails.aspx?SID=19

It says the WSDL is here:

http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?wsdl

and this is my code:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?wsdl');
$result = $client->getQuote("AAPL");
echo $result;
```

I'm getting an error saying "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string". Now I realize that $result is an object, and I'm wondering how do I access data that the server populated? I tried to understand the WSDL but I'm getting nowhere. Is it supposed to be something like:

```
$result->price
```

? (That doesn't work by the way...)

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When curious about datatypes from the soapserver, use the [SoapClient->__getTypes()](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.soap-soapclient-gettypes.php)  & [SoapClient->__getFunctions()](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.soap-soapclient-gettypes.php) methods
2. If you return is still not clear, `var_dump()` your return and examine it.